# JAXP XSLT transformer using wrong implementation by default

Tags: java, xslt, tomcat, jaxp

I've got a Tomcat 5.5 web application that uses the Apache Commons-Configuration library to generate an XML configuration file at runtime. Commons-Configuration, in turn, uses the `javax.xml.transform` JAXP API to accomplish this.

Since upgrading to Java 7, the operation fails with the following error message:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

In past releases, I've never bundled xalan.jar, instead relying on the platform default XSLT implementation.

Some things I've checked:

- There are no `META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` entries in any of my application JAR files, library jars, or in the Tomcat jars
- The `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` system property is unset (verified at runtime through JVisualVM)
- There is no `jaxp.properties` file in the `jre/lib` directory

Running with `-Djaxp.debug=1` produces the following output:

```
JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
JAXP: loaded from fallback value: org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

Where's this fallback value coming from? Oracle ships the Xalan transformer, but since 1.7 has repackaged it as `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.processor...`. Shouldn't *that* be the fallback value?

Comment: Did you check `CATALINA_HOME/lib`?

Comment: Tomcat 5.5 doesn't use `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. Afaik that's Tomcat 6+. I've checked in `$CATALINA_HOME/server`, `common`, and `shared` to no avail.

Comment: The class `org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl` could be from an older JDK1.4 setup, so I'm expecting there to be a fishy xalan.jar somewhere on your `CLASSPATH`

Comment: BTW, according to the [apache docs CATALINA_HOME is supported](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html). That link describes the classpath in detail which may help you check the appropriate directories for the offending jar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the issue myself. It turns out that I had the `apache-tomcat-5.5.23-compat` files installed, as I was migrating from Java 1.4.2. The solution was to remove everything under the `$CATALINA_HOME/common/endorsed` directory (in particular `xercesImpl.jar` and `xml-apis.jar`) and the `bin/jmx.jar` files.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue i was also getting with Glassfish server V3.1 and by placing xalan-2.7.0.jar in $GLASSFISH_HOME\lib\endorsed directory the issue is resolved.