# Any XML JARS I missing?

Tags: java, selenium, xslt, ant

I seeing the same error when executing "ant makexsltreports" from command line.

BUILD FAILED

```
/Users/xiaoyu/Documents/workspace/Learning_testNG/build.xml:95: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
```

Which XML JARS I missing? I got "xml-apis.jar" already imported into my project.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you upgraded your java version?see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284131/jaxp-xslt-transformer-using-wrong-implementation-by-default

Comment: If you want to use Saxon 9 then you need to download and add `saxon9he.jar` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/latest/download?source=files to your classpath.

Comment: I added saxon9he.jar into build path but still show the same error:BUILD FAILED
/Users/xiaoyu/Documents/workspace/Learning_testNG/build.xml:95: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
 at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:187)

Answer (score 0):

I got my issue resolved today. It is because in my build.xml file I didn't put "saxon-8.7.jar" into jar folder(`<property name="ws.jars" value="/Users/xiaoyu/Documents/softWare/jars"/>`).